# What are the standard containers that do not require CopyAssignable/CopyConstructible?

Tags: c++11, containers

Until C++11, I think `std::vector<T>` required `T` to be CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible for basic operations (extending the capacity would require copying object to another memory location). But if you do `v1 = v0`, I assume that it would to actually copy the values.

Are there any standard containers that do not require for any of their functions their `value_type` to be assignable and copyable ?

To say it otherwise, I have a type that has is not copyable/assignable, which containers are safe to use portably and to what extent ?

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

> The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements.

Notably `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` (for some complete T) is a non-CopyAssignable / non-CopyConstructible container.

Comment: It actually does not: i have a class with a delete copy constructor and the same code works fine with g++ 6/7 but fails with g++ 5.4. Likely because copies have been replaced by moves.